# Why does the program who has a embeded manifest with CRT version 30729.4148 runs with 30729.6161(latest) in winsxs folder on runtime?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, crt

I have a question really really wondering.

I installed various versions of visual studio 2008 redistribution package in my machine. 
Now, 30729.6161 is up to date.

In this environment, I made a simple program with embeded manifest which only refer to 30729.4148 CRT runtime library.

But, when I ran the program, this has loaded not a 30729.4148 version of CRT library but 30729.6161.

Why does this work?

Comment: Take a look at the wiki article for Windows Side-by-Side Assembly http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side-by-side_assembly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The new runtime comes with policy files that redirects clients with older versions to the newer version.

See:

```
%WinDir%\WinSxS\Policies
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to make an application configuration file, such as MyApp.exe.config, and set a redirection element which informs the application that using 30729.4148 CRT library for all of 30729.x version. In runtime, but, my application still load the 30729.6161 latest CRT library. My solution is wrong?

Comment: Well, it's the task of the policy files to redirect to new version. Why should the OS load the old files for your application?

Comment: I really wonder that my application can load specific version of dll using manifest.